# How to create blank excel file at sharepoint through azure logic app

Tags: excel, azure, sharepoint

I have designed a logic app that calls a function which return content byte. logic app then creates reads those content byte and create file at share point.
But of content byte is null, it fails.
I tried added a check for null in logic app and skip if null. But I wish to create blank excel file in case it is null.
Though i have implemented this through a work around where if content by is null, function app creates blank file and then return content byte of blank file.

Is there any way to avoid creating blank file through function and directly logic app creates file file if content byte is blank.

Comment: I think the $600/month charge for the integration account is going to keep people away from helping on this one. I assume you work for a large company that can afford the integration account, we gave up and used python lol. Just off the top of my head, can you copy a base template file inside logic app?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in this way -

- created function app to create a blank excel.
- Function app returns bye array of blank excel to logic app
- logic app then uploads excel to sharepoint.